# How to handle inherited roles in user stories?

Tags: agile, scrum, user-story

I'm having struggles how dealing with inherited roles. Here is an example :

```
As an admin, I want to do something 1
As an admin, I want to do something 2
As a super admin, I want to do something 3
```

So basically the super admin has the same privileges as the admin with some extra features. My problem is, how can I express that the super admin needs to do these actions too (something 1 and something 2)? Do I have to re-create the exact same story for both roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways of handling this.

If the concept of "super admin" and "admin" both exist when implementing the work for the first time, then you should make it clear that a "super admin" is a superset of "admin" users. If you have user classes or personas, this would be captured there. You can also capture acceptance criteria on the individual user stories to ensure that the implementer knows to design and test around both users of "admin" type and users of "super admin" type to ensure they can or cannot do the right things.

If the concept of "super admin" was introduced later, then the first step would be to test to confirm if a "super admin" can perform the intended behavior. For any behaviors that a "super admin" should be able to do, but not, that work should be appropriately tracked and prioritized. Whether that's one work item to go and correct the problem across all actions or many smaller ones would depend on the effort to implement each one.